# Do people ever lie in "The Expanse"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-expanse

A quite strange question, and my first one here, so please be gentle.

I just watched "The Expanse", first season. It just came to my mind, **is there ever anyone telling a lie?** With the definition of lie as follows:

- Something a character intentionally says that is not true/contradicts something else (in-universe), as far as the watcher of the show knows.

Note: There are obvious scenes where the truth is not told, for example in the interrogations at the MCRN Donnager after the crew got rescued. But still, AFAIK there are just things not told, no lies.

Comment: UN Undersecretary Errinwright is running an entire campaign of deception. There's gotta be some lies in what he says, I'd think.

Comment: I think you may be right. There are few if any direct lies in the show, though perhaps I'll be keeping an eye out for them now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fred Johnson lies about his status as OPA.  (He denies association, as I recall, when he is actually one of the leaders.)

Avasarala also lies to her old friend in order to get Mars to inadvertently reveal strategic information.

*[Sorry I don't have episode numbers--been a while since I watched it.  I can assure you that in the books, there is a healthy amount of traditional lying, not just lying by omission.]*

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However about Avasarala, AFAIK, they actually captured the alleged OPA courier Sobong, which would render the leakage of that information to Ambassador DeGraaf (the old friend) a possible  truth, or am I wrong?

Comment: As I recall, the leak was accurate information, but she lied to her old friend about what was actually going on. This subsequently got the old friend banned from returning to Mars where he'd planned to retire.

Answer (score 1):

I found at least one example!

In Season 2 Episode 7 (*The Seventh Man*) at the 23 minute 48 second mark:

> Anderson Dawes says to James Holden, "Fred Johnson is tactical. He can't think any other way. He wouldn't-a offered me up to the inner planets as his errand boy or be willing to return Earth's missiles so readily unless he had another card to play." Holden responds, knowing about the existence of the protomolecule, and knowing that Fred Johnson knows it too, "Hmm, none that we know of. Now get off my ship."